# Linear Maps: Why is it suffice to prove $T(u+av) = T(u)+aT(v)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I was wondering the following.

I know by definition,

Suppose that $V$ and $W$ are vector spaces over the same field, $F$. Let $T: V \rightarrow W$ be a function. We say $T$ is linear if:

$(1) \; T(u+v)=T(u)+T(v)$  for every $u, v \in V.$

$(2) \;T(av) = aT(v)$ for every $a \in F$ and $v \in V$.

Now my question is why is it sufficient to show that $(3)$: $T(u+av)=T(u)+aT(v)$ for all $u,v \in V$ and $a \in F$.

I have always taken statement 1 and 2 to be a definition but surely (3) is not a definition. So where does it come from?

Answer (score 1):

If we have $T(u+av) = T(u) + aT(v)$ for all $u,v \in V$ and all $a \in F$, then we have:

For $a=1$: $T(u+v) = T(u) + T(v)$ which is condition 1.

For $u=0$: $T(av) = aT(v)$ which is condition 2.

In other words, by proving the third statement, we have shown both (1) and (2) at the same time.

Comment: @Bobby Glad I could help. Consider accepting the answer if you are satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

If either of $(1)$ or $(2)$ is false, then there exists a counterexample to $(3)$.

So if $(3)$ is true, then both of $(1)$ and $(2)$ must be.